# A question about the equality of heat and changes in enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics

I am wondering how the heat release or absorbed by a chemical reaction can be equal to the change in enthalpy of the reaction at constant pressure if there are changes in the amounts and potentials of each chemical in the reaction mixture. To be more specific, at constant pressure,

$$\mathrm dH = T\,\mathrm dS + \sum_{i} {\mu_i\,\mathrm dN_i}$$

How can we just ignore the summation for something like a chemical reaction?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of non-PV work (at constant pressure), the change in enthalpy of the system is equal to the heat exchanged between system and surrounding. This follows from the first law of thermodynamics and the definition of enthalpy.

The equation you are showing is based on the definition of the Gibbs energy (the chemical potential is defined via the Gibbs energy, and the Gibbs energy and the internal energy are different by TS). Just because you define some new thermodynamic functions and express the change in enthalpy with it does not invalidate the first law of thermodynamics.

> How can we just ignore the summation for something like a chemical reaction?

Here is a silly calculation to model what is going on. Let's start with a variable $a$ known to be five:

$$a = 5$$

Now we add $b$ to both sides:

$$a + b = 5 + b$$

Let's define a new variable to simplify the right hand side:

$$c = 5 + b$$

and substitute that into the equation:

$$a + b = c$$

Now we solve for a:

$$a = c - b$$

It looks like $a$ depends on $b$ and $c$. However, we know $a$ is equal to 5, so it is constant. If you substitute the definition of $c$ back into the bottom equation, you get back to $a = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult question you have asked, and it has taken me a few days to figure out the answer.  This question is closely related to a Challenge Problem that I issued in PhysicsForums.com 3 years ago.  Even though I knew the answer to the challenge problem, it still took me significant time to figure out the connection to your question.  Here is the link to the challenge problem:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/thermochemistry-challenge-problem-chets-paradox.913567/

Consider the relationship between your question and the following part of the challenge problem:  **If the pressures in states 1 and 2 are the same, why is the change in entropy of the system not equal to the change in enthalpy divided by the temperature?**

The solution to this paradox posed by the challenge problem was masterfully provided by member Dr. Du in post #2.